# Problems setting rowId while using jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Background Information.**

I have a jquery datatable which is working fine... except for the fact that after my page / table renders... it's missing a row id.
I need each row to look something like this:

```
 <tr id=10100... > ... </tr>
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected = [];
    $('#users').DataTable( {
        "processing": false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ordering": false,
        aLengthMenu: [
            [10, 25, 50, 100, "-1"],  //controls the "Show X entries" drop down on gui
            [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
        ],
        "ajax": "/cgi-bin/mvspaging_list",
        rowId:'pn',
        "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
            if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
                $(row).addClass('selected');
            }
        },
    "columns": 
    [    
        //{ "data": "id" ,"searchable":false},
        { "data": "pn", "searchable":true },   
        { "data": "fname",defaultContent:'', "searchable":true},
        { "data": "lname",defaultContent:'',"searchable":true},
        { "data": "grp_name",defaultContent:'',"searchable":true},  
        { "data": "description",defaultContent:'',"searchable":true},               
        { "mRender": function ( data, type, row) {          
            if (row.grp == 0) {
                action =  '<a href=pndetails.html?pn=' + row.pn +'>Details</a>';
                var fullname= encodeURI(row.fname + " " + row.lname);
                action = action + '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' + '<a href="#" onclick=delpn(' + row.pn + ',"' + fullname + '",false)>Delete</a>';
                return action;
            } else {
                var groupname= encodeURI(row.grp_name);
                action =  '<a href=group_details.html?pn=' + row.pn +'>Details</a>';
                action = action + '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' +  '<a href="#" onclick=delpn(' + row.pn + ',"' + groupname + '",true)>Delete</a>';
                return action;      
            }
            }
        }
    ]
    });
} );
```

Currently, this generates HTML rows like this:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>10100</td>
      <td>Devin</td>
      <td>Daster</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><a href="pndetails.html?pn=10100">Details</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="delpn(10100,&quot;Devin%20Daster&quot;,false)">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
```

I thought specifying

```
  rowId:'pn',
```

would do the trick but I guess not.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing would be appreciated.  I'm currently using this as a reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId

Answer (score 1):

I added / changed my call back like so:

```
    "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
        console.log(data);
        $(row).attr('id', data.pn);
    },
```